# Does Apple make anything public about how email delivery for me/mac/icloud.com happens?

Tags: icloud, email

I'm trying to troubleshoot some email delivery issues for users on me.com/mac.com and I can't find any documentation from Apple about how they do spam filtering, etc. (see AOL Postmaster for an example of what I'm talking about)

I get the impression that this is intentionally obscured, but I thought I'd ask anyhow.

Comment: isn't it just standard old IMAP or POP3?

Comment: I assume it is, but what I'm looking for is information for people doing bulk email sending.

Comment: So their spam can get past the filter:-)